# Which database should i prefer?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, contacts

I am thinking of storing persons contact data centrally. So there will be so many persons and each will have their contact list. There will be more number of updates and selects on database as user will be searching their contacts or searching for a person not in his/her contact list. Person may be updating their contact details. But inserts in database will be limited because only one time enrollment will be there. I am confused in using databases MySQL or Neo4j. Because when I think of searching person from database neo4j seems better. But when I think of handling millions of records MySQL seems better. So can anyone suggest which database suits best? MySQL/Neo4j/ both MySQL and Neo4j or some other database?

Comment: This question is ABSOLUTELY impossible to answer, you're asking about software without taking hardware into account. No matter what program you run, it **depends** on hardware. Any kind of storage layer is so dependent on HDD subsystem and RAM that it's a waste of time considering MySQL, Neo4j, MSSQL, NoSQL or anything else. It doesn't matter what you use if you have slow hardware, no program will make it run exceptionally fast or do what you want.

Comment: Omitting hardware from the decision process: the question is still an *opinion* question. Lots of database engines to select from, each with pros and cons, each with fans and opponents. Unfortunately StackOverflow is not the place for a question like this, because it will yield lots of opinions. Perhaps Quora would be a much better fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j allows you to store the connections between the people via their contacts, so if you want to leverage the network effect in your application it makes sense to look into that.

It all depends on how you want people to search and interact with your app. If treat people as individual records with no connections then MySQL is good enough. Otherwise Neo4j would probably work better.

IF you have the time to a tiny PoC with some realistic data with both and then decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MySQL latest version it is quite simple and relevant to your need , you need to just use locking system on your database or you can lock your table when inserting or updating.